# ORACLE REGEX to add delimiter after every file name

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have got few files which are by separated by multiple spaces, I wrote a regex which would remove all the white spaces but not able to add the delimiter after end of every file. Can you please assist?

```
select regexp_replace(file,'[[:space:]]',',') from test_table
where id in ('1','2');
```

**The above select only works if there is a single space between files.**

1. Please note that files can be of any extension, also i see a few (.) appearing in between file names.
2. spaces are uneven in the data

**sample data**

| filename : |
| --- |
| this is the file sent.today .msg required mail.msg |
| aa.docx bb.docx cc.pdf |

**required output (delimiter added(,) after each file**

| filename : |
| --- |
| this is the file sent.today .msg, required mail.msg |
| aa.docx, bb.docx, cc.pdf |

Comment: REGEXP and Oracle don't know of a concept of "file" (not in the sense you mean it, anyway). What is a "file" in your strings? Any subtring of printable characters (not control characters and not whitespace characters), that includes at least one dot and does not end in a dot? Or what other definition do you have for "file" in your problem? Be careful with the answer; is `abc1.22` a "file"? What about `33.842`?

Comment: You can remove the white space, but you cannot replace it with a comma and blank? Please show us the expression you have written.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I don't understand your question. The comma must be added only after "files" (whatever that means), not everywhere there's white space.

Comment: @mathguy definition of file here is ```.docx or .pdf or .msg``` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(data,'(\.[a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z])','\1, \2')
```

Each group (behind parenthesis) in the regex will be matched to their number in the resulting string (ie \1 and \2)

Note also that this regex does not work for file type containing a number.

Comment: thanks but this adds a ```,``` after in between file name as well for example ```this, is the file sent.today .msg``` so after this a comma has been added. Also the file names would contain numbers as well

Comment: @Emma Sorry, I haven't escaped the dot in my answer, it is edited now and should work as intended.

Comment: Feel also free to add number like [a-zA-Z0-9] where you need it.

Comment: this works like a charm !!!!! you made my day. would you please add the number as well, I tried adding but its not working :(

Comment: @Emma it really depend of your specification.  For instance a file extension starting with a letter followed by letter or number could be represented by  '(\.[a-zA-Z[]a-zA-Z0-9]+)  ([a-zA-Z0-9])'

Answer (score 1):

You explained that you can consolidate whitespace to single spaces. That has to be done separately from the "adding of commas" anyway, so let's say that's done.

You need a second REGEXP pass on the result of the first. Something like this:

```
regexp_replace(result_of_first_pass, '\.(docx|pdf|msg) ', '.\1, ')
```

Comment: thanks much for your help, can this be include in a dynamic sql query?

Comment: @Emma - (1) What is a "dynamic sql query"? (I ask because I assume you are not using the term in the proper technical sense). (2) I asked you *specifically* and you said "file" means .docx, .pdf or .msg. But in the Accepted Answer (which is not this one) you will also capture .txt and .file etc. So, which one is it? And you ask about adding digits to the solution. There is no digit in the answer you gave me, even though I asked you *specifically* about digits; so, which one is it? Until I understand your answer to such trivial questions, I don't know if I can help further.